# .Net Core EF core, another instance with same key for id exists when i try add entity?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am adding data from an Api into a database, the tables i am using have foreign keys on them so i am using the below to empty the tables.

```
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Delete from [ReportDatabase].[dbo].[To]");
```

However, every other time I run the job, it fails with this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Ticket' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'id'} is already being tracked.

My add function is:

```
public void Add(TEntity entity) => this.dbSet.Add(entity);
```

and I call complete after I have added all my entries.

Does anyone know if there is a way of syncing the context I feel like this is because the SQL statements are causing my `dbcontext` to go out of sync?

Comment: add all the code your problem i not in the code shown. you are tracking the same instance twice.

Comment: Most of the time this happens when your read model is different from your write model(add some code to get better answer)